# How to say $|f(x)|> M - \epsilon$ is a open set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to say the set $|f(x)|> M - \epsilon$ is a open set, where $M$ is the maximum of $|f|$ on [0,1]. It is a step in my proof of the below question:

$X=[0,1], \mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on [0,1]. $f \in C[0,1]$, show that $||f||_\infty = \max_{[0,1]} |f(x)|$

My proof is $|f|$ is continuous on a compact space, thus $|f|$ attains its maximum. Denote M is the maximum of $|f|$ on [0,1]. I need to prove $||f||_\infty = M $.

By definition, $||f||_\infty = \inf \{\alpha \in [0, \infty): \mu(\{ x: |f(x)|>\alpha   \}=0) \}$.

Notice that M is one of $\alpha$, since $\mu (\emptyset)=0$.

Now I want to say, any $\epsilon >0, M-\epsilon$ is not one of $\alpha$.

Comment: $\{ |f(x)| > M - \epsilon \} = \{ |f(x)| \le M - \epsilon \}^c = (f^{-1}([-M + \epsilon, M - \epsilon]))^c$ is open, since $f$ is continuous, the continuous preimage of a closed set is closed, and the complement of a closed set is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that the set $|f|^{-1}\left\{(M-\epsilon,\infty)\right)
\}$ is open, since it's the inverse image of an open interval and |f| is continuous. Now, all we need to show it is not empty as a non empty open set must contain a set of non zero measure. |f| is continuous on [0,1], so |f| achieves a minimum $m$ and a max $M$. Now, you're equipped to show that this set is non empty. The IVT might be handy

Comment: What's IVT for? It's non-empty as the point where $|f| = M$ belongs to it, right?

Comment: Absolutely true.. what was I thinking!